# Connect To Oracle 11g from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 and Oracle 11.2 g
i want to connect from android application to my orcl database
i build an application like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.houssam.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    Connection connection = null;
    try {// Load the Oracle JDBC driver
        String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driverName);
        // Create a connection to the database
        String serverName = "localhost";
        String serverPort = "1521";
        String sid = "orcl";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" +     serverPort + ":" + sid;
        String username = "bmanager";
        String password = "b";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username,     password);
        tv.setText("Successfully Connected to the database!");
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        tv.setText("Could not connect to the database " +     e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        tv.setText("Could not find the database driver " +     e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

i copy ojdbc7.jar to ..MyApplication\app\libs and in Android Studio I do this:
right click on app and click (Open Module Settings) and in (Dependencies) add Jar dependency and choose my MyApplication\app\libs\ojdbc7.jar
I use YouWave as emulator but when I run my application it show (Could not find the database driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
what i should do to resolve this
thanks

Comment: I don't think we can connect Oracle directly. Database used in Android is SQLite.

Comment: From Android, you will normally use a web service to connect to an Oracle database (or any other database for that matter). The database /JDBC code is on the server side.